# upgrade `file` command to latest version in mac os

Tags: macos, file

my current `file` command on my OSX
computer is :

```
$ file -v
file-5.04
magic file from /usr/share/file/magic
```

on my ubuntu server:

```
$ file -v
file-5.14
magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic
```

how to upgrade it in mac os?

I tried to use `brew install file-formula`, but error occurs `Error: No available formula for file-formula`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go [here](http://darwinsys.com/file/) you can click on the `FTP` link and download version 5.22.